Size of the Integral Sign in TeX Gyre Math Font and Conflict with \boldsymbol
I'm using luatex with the font TeX Gyre Terms Math. I followed one of the procedures in this post to get the integral signs to be large, as the standard size is way too small. Curiously, though, it seems that there is a clash between the procedure I used and the command \boldsymbol, as \boldsymbol seems to break the behavior of the integral.
Here's an MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\everydisplay{\Umathoperatorsize\displaystyle=5ex}
\begin{document}
\[\int a\]

\[\int \boldsymbol{a} \]
\end{document}

The output is this:


Each Unicode math font includes several sets of alhabets: italic, bold, bolditalic, sansserif, sansserifitalic, calligraphic, blackboard, ...
You can select bold italic letters using already loaded font. On the other hand, the bold variant of a math font is intended for different usage: for example, if you want to have whole formula to be bold because it is in a title where bold text font is selected.
The solution for your case should be:
$$\int \symbfit a $$


There is no boldface for TeX Gyre Termes Math, so if you really want \boldsymbol you have to use a different font, for instance XITS Math Bold. Since the Termes integral symbol is really short, you can substitute it with the one from STIX Two Math, with stylistic set 08 to make it upright.
A few tricks are needed to avoid annoying warnings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[NFSSFamily=tgtm]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[NFSSFamily=stm,StylisticSet=08,range=\int]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[NFSSFamily=tgtm,range=]

\DeclareFontShape{TU}{tgtm}{b}{n}{<-> ssub* tgtm/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{stm}{b}{n}{<-> ssub* stm/m/n}{}

\begin{document}

\[\int a\]

\[\int \boldsymbol{a} \]

\end{document}


